# Liferay 7 - Get Assets Comments from ADT

Tags: java, templates, liferay, adt, freemarker

I'm trying to get the comments of an entry in an ADT.
I tried this:

```
<#assign MBMessageLocalServiceUtil = serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.message.boards.kernel.service.MBMessageLocalServiceUtil")> 

<@getCommentCount resourcePrimKey=article.getResourcePrimKey()/>

<#macro getCommentsCount resourcePrimKey>
<#assign Messages = MBMessageLocalServiceUtil.getMessages("com.liferay.portlet.journal.model.JournalArticle", resourcePrimKey, 0) />
<#assign MessagesCount = Messages?size-1 />
<#if MessagesCount != 0> 
(Comments: ${MessagesCount} )
</#if>
</#macro>
```

It throws me this error then:

```
The following has evaluated to null or missing:
==> serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.message.boards.kernel.service.MBMessageLocalServiceUtil")  [in template "20116#20160#38923" at line 35, column 54]
```

I really have no Idea what I am doing wrong.
I've already used the serviceLocator on this portal and it works. Freemarker restricted Variables and Classes are removed.

Does anyone has an Idea for a Soloution ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **/comment.commentmanagerjsonws/get-comments** action from the [liferay jsonws api](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/invoking-json-web-services) to access the entry comments. This api is accessible per Javascript / curl / URL, it should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

In Liferay 7 the configuration was moved from `portal.properties` to the new OSGi configuration. See this [thread](https://web.liferay.com/de/community/forums/-/message_boards/view_message/73386692#_19_message_74729187) for details.